# Error Generating RSpec

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I've created a new Rails project directory and I have just edited the .gemfile; I'm working my way through Michael Hartl's tutorial.  I have the revised .gemfile now in place.  It states next to 'rails generate rspec:install' which I have ran in my command prompt; however, it now gives me the following errors:

```
/Users/coreymkimball/Canvi/Projects/TheCanvi.com/RoR/The_Canvi/config/initializers/secret_token.rb:27:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant The_Canvi (NameError)
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:609:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `each'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:209:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:203:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/Canvi/Projects/TheCanvi.com/RoR/The_Canvi/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:45:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Can anyone me help out?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your error message, it says `uninitialized constant The_Canvi`. This means that when the code is ran, it is looking for a constant (most likely a class) by that name, but rails can't find it. This is actually an odd naming convention for the ruby community in general. As a tip, when creating a new rails app you should make the name of your app in all lowercase, and then separate each word by an underscore.

In your example, I would suggest `rails new the_canvi`. This will generate the app using the constant TheCanvi as your main application class name. This would be the same for all of your models, controllers, and whatnot.

Since this is just a new tutorial, try and delete the app, then start fresh. It's always good practice getting used to building a new app anyway.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, man; that's great- appreciate the feedback, definitely.